# How to count the non-blank cell regardless it's format in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to count the non-empty cell in Perl.
The problem is that cell_index counts up to 9 but I expected 8.
I think it counts with formatted cell too.

How do I count the cell containing only string or numbers not formatted empty cell in Perl?

```
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
use XML::LibXML;
...
while ( $worksheet->get_cell($cell_index , 1) ne '' ) {
  $cell_index++;                                  
print $cell_index ,"\n";                          
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "empty". Your code checks the contents of the cell against the empty string. But that's not the only thing that might look empty. Just off the top of my head, a cell might appear empty if it contains:

- Absolutely nothing (which might be represented in Perl code by `undef`)
- The empty string (the case that you cover)
- One or more white-space characters (spaces, tabs, stuff like that)

The safest test might be to count cells that contain no non-whitespace characters - which you can do easily with a regex.

```
$worksheet->get_cell($cell_index , 1) =~ /\S/
```